# Position/number uncertainty relation for the eigenstate of a Harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Position and number operators for a Harmonic oscillator manifestly do not commute:
$$
\hat{n}=a^\dagger a,\\
\hat{x}=\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega_0}}(a + a^\dagger),\\
[\hat{x},\hat{n}]= \sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega_0}}(a - a^\dagger) =\frac{i\hat{p}}{m\omega_0},
$$
which means that they are related via an uncertainty relation. However, if we take the uncertainty relation in [its most frequently used form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Robertson%E2%80%93Schr%C3%B6dinger_uncertainty_relations),
$$
\sigma_A\sigma_B\geq \frac{1}{2}|\langle[A,B]\rangle|,
$$
and assume averaging over an oscillator eigenstate (i.e. an eigenstate of $\hat{n}$), $|n\rangle$, then the commutator in the right-hand side is zero:
$$
\sigma_x\sigma_n \geq 0,
$$
which is trivial and not very useful.

Is there a stricter form of uncertainty relation which would be mor emeaningful here? (Or perhaps I am missing some finer point about the averaging in the derivation of the uncertainty relations?)

Comment: see Carruthers, P., and Michael Martin Nieto. "Phase and angle variables in quantum mechanics." Reviews of Modern Physics 40.2 (1968): 411.,

Comment: It must be so. Since the $\sigma_n$ in the left-hand side is also zero for a eigen state of number operator $n$.

Comment: @ytlu good point!

Comment: @Vadim An eigenstate of $\hat n$ cannot have arbitrarily small $\sigma_x$. We could quantify this and call it an uncertainty relation. Would that make a satisfactory answer?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly indeed, we could calculate variance, and ut us finite. I think ytlu gave the correct answer - $\sigma_n=0$, so the product is zero, even if $\sigma_x$ is finite.